# Does bouncing a stolen card return it back to the original owner?

Tags: mythgard

What happens if my opponent stole one of my minions (using traitorious murmur for example) and I bounce it (using deported for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens depends on who is meant to recieve the card back, in deported's case it says "owner's hand". Owner being the person that had the card at the beginning of the game, it'll be returned to your hand.

If the card would mention controller though, the minion would be returned to opponent's hand.

This logic is applyable not only to creatures but also artifacts, enchantments and brands.